# What is the conventional name/notation for the function $ N(n) = \begin{cases} 1 & n \le 0 \\ n & n > 0 \end{cases}$?

Tags: functions, notation, terminology

I am wonder what the conventional name/notation for this function:

$$ N(n) = \begin{cases}  1 & n \le 0 \\ n & n > 0 \end{cases}$$

I assume its use is frequent enough that there is such a thing. If not, I'll simply define it like I have above.

Comment: I think the concept of piece-wise functions is common enough.  But there are an infinite variety of them I doubt this particular one has a name.  You could call it the "the identity if positive and constant one if not" function if you want.

Comment: Assuming $n$ is an integer, you can write this as $\max(n,1)$, which is known as a [rectifier function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rectifier_(neural_networks)) in neural networks.

Comment: @p.s. I see, I might use $R(n)$ as my notation then. Or, I can just use the max function, as it is pretty compact to begin with.

Comment: It can be written as $f(n)=1+(n-1)\chi_{(0,\infty)}(n),$ but I doubt this function has its own name or notation.